# Jquery making array within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create an array in jquery. I need this array to have multiple other arrays in them.

My code now:

```
      var arr = [];

     $('.thumb').each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).attr('data-storename'),$(this).attr('data-grid-item-id')); 
 });
```

This gives me just 1 array with all the data-storename's and data-grid-item-id's in it.

I want my array to look like :

```
0 [

   0 =>   data-storename : (someinfo)
   1 =>   data-grid-item-id : (someinfo)
]


1 [

   0 =>   data-storename : (someinfo)
   1 =>   data-grid-item-id : (someinfo)
]
```

and so on.

All my attempts end up being one single array, but just nested inside another array. Any help?

Comment: `arr.push([..., ...]);` in the `each()`.

Comment: If you want to push an array, you need to push an array.

Comment: IMO, avoid broken, standards-defying APIs. JS now handles Array-like objects anyway.  `Array.from($('.thumb'), function (el) { return [..., ...] })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can use `map()` to create the outer array. You can then return an array containing the two values you require from the `map()` handler function. Try this:

```
var arr = $('.thumb').map(function(){
    return [[$(this).data('storename'), $(this).data('grid-item-id')]];
}).get()
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/efzy4u84/)

Comment: Don't you have to `return` in the `map()`

Comment: @Tushar thanks. Wrote that in the description, then forgot to actually put it in the example XD

Comment: Still, `return arr.push(...` ==> `return [..., ...]`

Comment: i get the console arror : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(anonymous function)

Comment: yeah - `return arr.push(...)` that will return the new _length_ of `arr`, not the array itself.

Comment: @vlaz so how would I get the array ?

Comment: tada -> `$.map($('.thumb'),e=>[[$(e).data('storename'), $(e).data('grid-item-id')]]);`

Comment: I guess put the `arr.push(...)` on a separate line then just `return arr;` on the next one but I've not actually looked thoroughly at that code - just spotted that the return is wrong. Or what @adeneo suggests, actually. In ES5 you can also just return a new array instead of that `arr`.

Comment: @petervries apologies, I updated the answer with the correct syntax. I was having a complete brain fart

Comment: Just be aware the arrow functions are not supported in older browsers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - no problem, that `get()` part is really easy to forget, and is why I like `$.map` instead.

Comment: With `push` -> `$('.thumb').toArray().reduce( (a,b) => {return a.push([$(b).data('storename'), $(b).data('grid-item-id')]),a}, []);`